# Fetch Virtual Machine Information

Tags: c#, virtual-machine

I am working on a web application. The requirement of this application is, that the user would provide the ip address and hostname of a virtual machine.Then the application is supposed to return some information(RAM,HDD,No OF CPU etc.) of that virtual machine. I am pretty new to this. Please help me with this. If possible i would like to avoid the use any API for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The question is too broad. But the *idea* behind this is simple.

You need "someone" on that machine that talk to you about the `RAM`, `HDD`, `CPU` etc of it. So you basically will need a program that waits request from you, gets it, and respond to you an information you need.

It can be some resident program that runs on startupt, or some Windows Service (if VM is Windows actually), WCF service, HTTP server.. etc.

Comment: So basically, it is not possible to get this information through web and we need to install the windows service etc. physically to the machine to fetch the required information?

Comment: sure, consider also strong security issures arround it. I don't know where physiscal your VM is, but basically it usually acts like a machine in LAN, with all security aplpied.